# java Loop through variables with a common name

Tags: java, string, for-loop, int, processing

I'm trying to create 10 variables with random numbers, all beginning with the same word, like:
- Foo1
- Foo2
- Foo3
- Foo4

What I'm trying is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i += i){
  int name = int("Foo" + i)
  name = random(100, 500);
  image(blabla, blabla, name);  //the blabla are fixed coordinates
};
```

However I cannot get this to work.
Do you guys know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically, don't do this. Create an array instead. Then you can use `foo[i] = random(100, 500);` etc.

Comment: int name = int("Foo" + i) and name = Math.random(100, 500) don't compile.  That could be part of the problem.

Comment: @PaulJAbernathy This is Processing, not strict Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array.

An array is a variable that holds multiple values.

```
int[] r = {1, 2, 3};
int x = r[0];
```

[Here](https://www.processing.org/reference/Array.html) is the Processing array reference.

Here is how you might do this in your example:

```
PImage[] images = new PImage[20];
images[0] = loadImage(...);
//..load rest of images

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i += i){
  image(blabla, blabla, images[i]);
}
```

You also might want to look into the [ArrayList](https://www.processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) or [HashMap](https://www.processing.org/reference/HashMap.html) classes.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked and it seems to be more oprimised then the way I would have done it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a variable programmatically, you have to use reflection, however it is not a good solution for anyone except experienced programmer designing high level API.
You should use an ArrayList for your variables.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Map. For instance

```
Map<String, Integer> vars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    vars.put("Foo" + i, (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 500) + 100);

System.out.println(vars.get("Foo8")); // Accessing to Foo8 value
```